# How to pick element inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I have an embed code for a donation form

```
<div id="raisely-donate" data-campaign-path="zakat-almal" data-width="100%" data-height="800"><script src="https://cdn.raisely.com/v3/public/embed.js"></script><iframe src="https://zakat-almal.raisely.com/embed?targethost=https://ramadan.gimfoundation.org.au" style="border: none;" width="100%" height="850.4375"></iframe></div>
```

The iframe loads

```
<div id="donate" class="donation-form donation-form--active-step-1 " data-form-uuid="ec089aef-6d40-4fa0-a663-2104ae15e217"><div class="donation-form__header"><div class="donation-form__stages donation-form__stages--total-4"><div role="button" tabindex="0" class="donation-form__stage donation-form__stage--0 donation-form__stage--active">1</div><div role="button" tabindex="0" class="donation-form__stage donation-form__stage--1" disabled="">2</div><div role="button" tabindex="0" class="donation-form__stage donation-form__stage--2" disabled="">3</div></div></div><div class="donation-form__body donation-form__body--amount"><div class="donation-form__amount-type"></div><div class="donation-form__amount donation-form__amount--width-full donation-form__amount--has-text"><button class="donation-form__amount-btn button--donation" type="button"><span class="donation-form__amount-value">$75</span><span class="donation-form__amount-title">Could provide a widow and orphans with essential food and non-food items for a whole month.</span></button><button class="donation-form__amount-btn button--donation" type="button"><span class="donation-form__amount-value">$200</span><span class="donation-form__amount-title">Could provide education for 10 vulnerable children for six months.</span></button><button class="donation-form__amount-btn button--donation" type="button"><span class="donation-form__amount-value">$500</span><span class="donation-form__amount-title">Could provide essential survival kits (including food, water and personal hygiene items) and shelter for a vulnerable family.</span></button><button class="donation-form__amount-btn button--donation" type="button"><span class="donation-form__amount-value">$2,000</span><span class="donation-form__amount-title">Could provide life-saving medicine and support the development of a health care facility in the most vulnerable areas.</span></button><button class="donation-form__amount-btn button--donation" type="button"><span class="donation-form__amount-value">$5,000</span><span class="donation-form__amount-title">Could support emergency medical interventions when crisis hits and in the months that follow.</span></button><div class="form-field form-field--text form-field--currency form-field--empty form-field--valid donation-form__other-field"><label for="Other Amount"><span class="form-field__label-text">Other Amount</span></label><div class="form-field__input-group"><span class="form-field__input-group__prepend">$</span><input name="amount" type="number" class="input-full" placeholder="Other" step="any" pattern="\d*" value=""></div></div></div><div class="donation-form__amount-currency"><hr>Donating in <span class="donation-form__currency">Australian Dollars<select class="donation-form__currency-select"><option value="ARS" name="Argentine Pesos">Argentine Pesos</option><option value="AUD" name="Australian Dollars">Australian Dollars</option><option value="BRL" name="Brazilian Reals">Brazilian Reals</option><option value="GBP" name="British Pounds">British Pounds</option><option value="CAD" name="Canadian Dollars">Canadian Dollars</option><option value="CNY" name="Chinese Renminbi Yuan">Chinese Renminbi Yuan</option><option value="EUR" name="Euros">Euros</option><option value="HKD" name="Hong Kong Dollars">Hong Kong Dollars</option><option value="INR" name="Indian Rupees">Indian Rupees</option><option value="IDR" name="Indonesian Rupiah">Indonesian Rupiah</option><option value="ILS" name="Israeli New Sheqels">Israeli New Sheqels</option><option value="JPY" name="Japanese Yen">Japanese Yen</option><option value="MXN" name="Mexican Pesos">Mexican Pesos</option><option value="TWD" name="New Taiwan Dollars">New Taiwan Dollars</option><option value="NZD" name="New Zealand Dollars">New Zealand Dollars</option><option value="RUB" name="Russian Rubles">Russian Rubles</option><option value="SAR" name="Saudi Riyals">Saudi Riyals</option><option value="SGD" name="Singapore Dollars">Singapore Dollars</option><option value="ZAR" name="South African Rand">South African Rand</option><option value="KRW" name="South Korean Won">South Korean Won</option><option value="SEK" name="Swedish Kronor">Swedish Kronor</option><option value="CHF" name="Swiss Francs">Swiss Francs</option><option value="USD" name="United States Dollars">United States Dollars</option></select></span></div></div></div>
```

I'm trying to change the value for name='amount' from inside the iframe, but can't seem to.

**This is JS I'm using**

```
document.getElementByName('amount').innerHTML = zakahCalculated;
```

Comment: Is iframe from same domain as page? If not you can't access it for security reasons

Answer (score 1):

Iframe content cannot be accessed if it is of a different origin.

```html
<iframe id='zakaform'></iframe>
```

To access the iframe content, the below snippets can be used. These snippets give a reference only when the iframe meets the [same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) policy.

```js
// to access iframe window
var iframeWindow = document.getElementById('zakaform').contentWindow;

// to access iframe document
var iframeDocument = document.getElementById('zakaform').contentDocument;

iframeDocument.getElementByName('amount').value = zakahCalculated;
```